# React Native - FlatList item not fit with screen with full width

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I'm using React Native to create a flatlist view with full-width items.
I set the item width to the screen width, but when I scroll to the next item, it exceeds the screen and causes some layout issues.

[image: Flatlist Item]

```js
const App = () => {
  const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'powderblue',
          padding: 10,
          margin: 5,
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          width: SCREEN_WIDTH
        }}
      >
        <Text>{item.id}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
  return (
    <View style={{
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: "flex-start",
      justifyContent: "flex-start",
      padding: 10
    }}>
      <FlatList
        pagingEnabled
        data={data}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        horizontal={true}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Have you tried  => Dimensions.get("screen").width

Comment: @ZhivkoNikolov thanks for the reply, I tried changing to screen but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the issue by removing the `flex`, `margin`, and `padding` in the renderItem View style, since this will cause the width not equal to the screen width.

The final code looks as follows:

```js
//const ITEM_WIDTH = SCREEN_WIDTH - PADDING_VALUE * 2;
const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("screen").width - 20;

const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'powderblue',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: SCREEN_WIDTH
      }}
    >
      <Text>{item.id}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

[Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@hazelwang/surprised-toffee) for result.